# Как в .NET Core запустить выполнение Powershell скрипта?

Tags: .net, веб-программирование, powershell

Доброго времени суток,

Есть необходимость запустить из .NET Core 2.0 скрипт Powershell 5.1 и получить результат его работы.

Хочу сделать удаленное управление некоторыми задачами через TelegramBot используя Webhook.

Буду очень благодарен

Comment: на сколько я знаю нельзя запустить повершел

Comment: вроде должны были в версии .NET Core 1.2 добавить поддержку?